# Vue Transition not working with v-autocomplete

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to conditionally show or hide a selection text field using Vue's `Transition`. Still, the text field pops up and leaves without any transition.

```
<template>
  <Transition
    v-if="isActive"
    name="fade"
  >
    <v-autocomplete
      :items="[1,2,3]"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </Transition>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const isActive = ref(false); // This will be toggled in a different location of the code
</script>


<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

I have tried different things, such as putting the `v-if` on the `v-autocomplete` component instead of the `Transition`, but I cant get it running. Here is an example on [Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

What am I doing wrong? If this is not possible with `Transition`, how can I achieve the same result anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `v-if` to the first child of it, not to the Transition.

```js
<Transition name="fade">
  <v-autocomplete
    v-if="isActive"
    :items="[1,2,3]"
  ></v-autocomplete>
</Transition>
```

- [Vue Example for Transition using](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component) - Vue Docs

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const isActive = ref(true)
    
    return { isActive }
  }
})
app.use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-btn @click="isActive = !isActive">Toggle</v-btn>
  <Transition name="fade">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-if="isActive"
      :items="[1,2,3]"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </Transition>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when I tried it, it didn't work. Now after your answer, it does work. I feel cheated.